# Can someone suggest some better way of writing this Javascript code

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am given an input array need to convert to output array (it's consecutive array in the output array.)

```
var input = [1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 40];
var output = [[1], [3, 4, 5], [8, 9], [15], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26], [40]];
```

I am able to achieve this by:

```
let t = 0;
let tArr = []
const a = [];
input.map(i => {
  if (i-t === 1) {  
    tArr.push(i);
  } else {
    a.push(tArr);
    tArr = [];
    tArr.push(i)
  }
  t = i;
});
a.push(tArr);
console.log("final", a)
```

Can someone suggest a cleaner code or if this could be optimized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reduce the array by looking at the index or ar the former value and compare to the actual value.

```js
var input = [1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 40],
    result = input.reduce((r, v, i, a) => {
        if (!i || a[i - 1] + 1 < v) {
            r.push([v]);
        } else {
            r[r.length - 1].push(v);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That was very quick

Comment: This was awestruck. Amazing. Thanks:D